# Condition for a year having 53 ISO 8601 weeks

Tags: algorithm, iso8601

[ISO_Week_Date's wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) says that there are three identical conditions for identifying whether a given year has 53 ISO 8601 weeks or not.

- any year starting on Thursday (dominical letter D or DC) and any leap year starting on Wednesday (ED)
- any year ending on Thursday (D, ED) and any leap year ending on Friday (DC)
- years in which 1 January and 31 December (in common years) or either (in leap years) are Thursdays

Assuming this is correct, each condition has a condition for a common year and a condition for a leap year. My logic was that they can be separated. Thus for a common year, the condition should be:

- the year starts on Thursday
- the year ends on Thursday
- the year starts and ends on Thursday

and for a leap year, the condition should be:

- the year starts on Wednesday or Thursday
- the year ends on Thursday or Friday
- the year starts or ends on Thursday

but each condition in the triplet does not seem to be equivalent to each of the other two. What is wrong with my interpretation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the regular year those are equivalent:

For a regular year the weekdays of January 1. and December 31. are the same. And if they are Thursdays the weeks containing them are counted towards the year so it has 53 weeks. Thus in a regular year if it starts on a Thursday it ends on one and has 53 weeks.

For a leapyear if either Jan 1. Or Dec 31.  are a Thursday it has 53. weeks. If Jan 1. Is a Thursday Dec. 31. will be a Friday and if Dec 31 is a Thursday then January 1. was a Wednesday.

So for the regular year all rules are equivalent and for the leap year the first two are the two distinct cases of the third.

Comment: So, is it possible to combine common year and leap year cases, and simply say: if either the beginning or the end of a year is Thursday, then it has 53 weeks?

Comment: @sawa-Your conclusion is right because if 365 days of ordinary year can cover this condition because of Thursday,then obviously 365 days' of leap year will surely do the same! hence,it is purely safe to conclude that!!!